# How to write a wrapper for the R code in Python

Tags: python, r, wrapper

Often in machine learning and statistics, a code or a package is developed in R language. Let's say the name of the package is "CodeA".  Sometimes you can find this package with the same name in another language like Python. When you go to the official python page for this package: it says this is a wrapper around the "CodeA" package in R for python users.

I am wondering what does it mean and how to write a wrapper in Python around R code?

I personally do not think they have implemented the code all over in python from scratch.

I would appreciate it if someone can explain how this can be done and what it means to write
a wrapper in python around R?

Comment: Look at the source and see how they did it? I'm guessing here, but I'd assume they have a `C++` code as they have linkers for that, and then they create boiler plate code to pipe calls from native Python/Cython to R via those C++ linkages. Have a look at https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate

Comment: You can run R code in Python using rpy2 python package https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/